OBS Studio virtual background plugin doesn't work
I use Gentoo for my desktop. I tried downloading and compiling the plugin source, but it has heavy dependencies for only one function, so I downloaded the precompiled deb.
The filter shows in webcam source filters, however it doesn't work. The terminal shows me this error:
info: [Virtual BG detector] detecter_create version:v1.2.0
error: [Virtual BG detector] Can't create session No graph was found in the protobuf.
info: Switched to scene 'Scene'

Is there something other than having to compile the source with all it's dependencies that could be done?

That plugin is no longer updated. You didn't mention any versions of it or OBS, but doesn't matter - there are better alternatives.
For example obs-backgroundremoval. It has e.g. Flatpak support, which should make it generally available on various Linux distros. It also has a lot more features, such as filter settings that allow adapting how much of the background is removed or if it should be blurred instead. And to have a different background you use it in the same way, layered on top of the new background.

I use OBS 30.1 Gentoo. I'm not a big fan of GNU/Linux binaries due to the incompatibility issues they come with, and the possibility some of their functions deactivated for any possible reason. I used the deb package in this case as last resort, and I was wondering if the error that I got was from something I could resolve or not. I checked on backgroundremoval filter, and it has the same dependencies as virtualbg so I resorted for the latter. I didn't try it's binary however!

I used backgroundremoval tool, and it worked. It needed some acrobatics, but it did the job. Thanks!
